# How can I undo damage done to a newly tiled floor?

Tags: tile, cleaning, damage

I feel I was (ill-)advised to clean my new beige, mat ceramic tiled floors using this recipe:

3 parts heated vinegar to 1 part water, brush solution in very vigourously with stiff floor-brush then leave for 4 hours and rinse.

As a result, I'm sure my split new tiles have become porous. When I now wash them with hot water my floor mop creates dreadful, irregular marks and scores everywhere. Even the tiniest mob hairs stick to the wet floor. Once dry these traces disappear but I'm firmly convinced I've damaged my new floors, which leaves me utterly devastated.

Please, please, can you help? Is there something I could use to restore some sort of protection?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you put down a tile and grout sealer after the vinegar soak?  The sealer is probably stripped and needs to be reapplied.  Do this first before and see how your floors are after.

Comment: "mat ceramic tiled floors", can you clarify? is this actually sheet vinyl flooring with a tile pattern?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The floor was laid and grouted professionally before I applied the vinegar solution ( on advice from a shop). After the severe treatment I thought I had damaged the grouting, too, but after a couple of weeks and additional central heating it eventually dried out and looks normal again. The tiles actually look completely normal except when I wash the floor. The floor cloth drags over the tiles which, once wet, take on a very strange, sort of mottled appearance: between crazy paving and a shattered windscreen.

Comment: Thank you, too, Cathode. The tiles are mat, ceramic. - Stoneware?

Comment: A photo of the wet floor displaying what you think is evidence of damage would help.